# How to set the style of 'DockedCells'?

Tags: docked-cell

I want to list R multiple sentences using 'Docked Cells' at the top of the notebook, and set each style and hyperlink.

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells -> Cell[Style["text"]] ]
```

The code above works well. However, the code below does not apply.

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
DockedCells -> Row[{  Cell[ Style["URL : ", 14, Bold, Blue]], 
Cell[Style[Hyperlink["http://www.wolfram.com"], 14, Bold]]}] ]
```

What part of the code should I modify?